# Bugsense Doesn't Report Crash

Tags: ios, bugsense

I have setup Bugsense in a Xcode 5.1 iOS 7.0 iPad application.

I get the following:

2014-04-04 00:35:45.801 ClearAsset[18858:1303] BugSense --> Posting analytics data...
2014-04-04 00:35:47.424 ClearAsset[18858:3c33] BugSense --> Server responded with status code: 200

But it doesn't create the JSON data after I simulate a crash and send it to Bugsense.

What could i be doing wrong?